# How can I filter out elements that only differ in class name?

Tags: cypress

I am trying to find a way to click on one of the buttons, the only difference between them locator-wise is the parent class. So the simplified locators for these elements would look something like this:

```
<div class="info-card-red">
<button type="button">click</button>

<div class="info-card-green">
<button type="button">click</button>

<div class="info-card-grey">
<button type="button">click</button>
```

They are all under a common parent class `<div class="info-card>`

The problem is that the environment changes dynamically, and I don't know which card and how many will be displayed. I need to click on a button under `info-card-red` or `info-card-green` but not on `info-card-grey`.

So I need a way to either single out pressing a button under any class that is NOT info-card-grey or to click a button under info-card-red OR info-card-green. I have not figured out how to implement OR in Cypress yet.

I tried this, but it didn't work :

```
cy.get('.info-card')
    .find('class')
    .not('.info-card-grey').eq(0)
    .find('button')
    .click()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your HTML looks like this (edited your sample to include closing divs)

```html
<div class="info-card">
  <div class="info-card-red">
    <button type="button">click red</button>
  </div>
    
  <div class="info-card-green">
    <button type="button">click green</button>
  </div>

  <div class="info-card-grey">
    <button type="button">click grey</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

then your test would be

```js
cy.get('.info-card')
  .find('[class^="info-card"]')          // yields red, green, grey
  .not('.info-card-grey')                // yields red, green
  .eq(0)                                 // yields red
  .should('have.class', 'info-card-red') // confirm the card you want is correct
  .find('button')
  .click()
```

The only real change to your test is `.find('class')` is looking for an element with tag "class", i.e `<class></class>`.

Using `[class^="info-card"]` in the selector means

- searching for an attribute (designated by `[...]`)
- which has key of `class` (`[class...]`)
- and value starting with (`^=`)
- the text `^="info-card"`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked for me, and I learned something new!